# Problemas con el buffer en estructuras con muchos datos c++

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

tengo esta estructura:

```
struct Alumno{
    string nombre;
    long ci;
    char sexo;
    int edad;
    string direccion;
    long telefono;
    Alumno*siguiente;
};
Alumno*listaAlumno=NULL;
```

y con esta funcion creo mis alumnos(antes decia que es una lista, pero gracias a un usuario me señalo que un nodo que apunta a otro no es una lista, asi que lo llamaremos arreglo de estructuras dinamicas enlazadas):

```
void insertarAlumno(Alumno*&listaAlumno){//le paso la referencia & para poder agregar elementos a la lista
    long cedula;
    //arreglo dinamico
    Alumno*nuevo_Alumno=new Alumno();
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"Ingrese Nombre y Apellido: ";
    getline(cin,nuevo_Alumno->nombre);
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"Ingrese Cedula: ";
    cin>>cedula;
    nuevo_Alumno->ci=cedula;
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"Ingrese sexo(M,F): ";
    cin>>nuevo_Alumno->sexo;
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"ingrese edad: ";
    cin>>nuevo_Alumno->edad;
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"ingrese Direccion: ";
    getline(cin,nuevo_Alumno->direccion);
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"ingrese telefono: ";
    cin>>nuevo_Alumno->telefono;
    fflush(stdin);
    //variables auxiliares para colocar el nodo al principio en medio o al final
    Alumno*aux1=listaAlumno;
    Alumno*aux2;
    //ordenamiento.. si la cedula ingresada es mayor el nuevo nodo se intercambiara posiciones hasta ponerse adelante
    while((aux1 != NULL)&&(aux1->ci < cedula)){
        aux2=aux1;//aux2 se intercambiaria con el primero
        aux1=aux1->siguiente;//y aux1 estaria apuntando al siguiente elemento de la lista
    }
    //se cumple si el nuevo nodo va al principio de la lista
    if(listaAlumno==aux1){
        listaAlumno=nuevo_Alumno;
    }
    //si no se cumple quiere decir que entro al ordenamiento
    else{
        aux2->siguiente=nuevo_Alumno;
    }
    //en todo caso el *siguiente de la estructura para llevar el la lista nodo->nodo->nodo
    nuevo_Alumno->siguiente=aux1;

    cout<<"\tTodos los datos del estudiante "<<nuevo_Alumno->nombre<<" Han sido registrados"<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

ahora donde esta mi problema?.. si quito todos los datos debajo de ci.. la funcion me trabaja bien.. pero si agrego ese poco de datos el buffer se vuelve todo loco y ni limpiando el buffer arreglo el problema (fijense que llene el algoritmo de de fflush).. que es lo que me sucede? que cuando voy a colocar el ultimo dato telefono no me deja ingresarlo.. y se procede a registrar el alumno y al volver al main el programa ingresa automaticamente en registrar alumno y entra en un ciclo donde no me deja hacer nada, como dije anteriormente si solo registro el nombre y la cedula el programa me trabaja bien.. el problem es al arregar esa cantidad de datos.. no me quiero imaginar cuando se empiece a trabajar con las relaciones estudiantes-asignaturas-profesor

Comment: Usar `fflush(stdin)` es comportamiento indefinido. Deberías evitarlo en tu código.